# ZoneId field with Audited

Tags: java, hibernate

I get an error from the entity marked @Audited with the field
`private ZoneId timezone`

Error:
`Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: zone-id, at table: manager_company_relation_aud, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(timezone)]`

Answer (score 0):

Used a converter

```
@Convert(converter = ZoneIdConverter.class)
private ZoneId timezone;
```